# how to remove email body in r

Tags: r, regex, email, extract, gsub

I'm trying to pull a specific data in emails from a single folder in outlook.

I read the data through ".csv" file currently (if any better option, pls let know) and able to get all the information in a "DT" form. The subject has 
`Thisispresent: FGD1-GRT1-1670946819-1069287620 ineverymail successfully`

I want to extract "FGD1-GRT1-1670946819-1069287620" which is dynamic, from the subject line and in the body "GRT1CFV1x1143468254x199". The matter in subject has a common factor where it starts with the second part in the string in subject (GRT1).

I tried extracting the subject using 
`str_extract(mail$Subject,"[:alnum:]+[:digit:]+[:digit:]")`
it gives `[1] NA           "1670946819"`

I desired output should have the subject (FGD1-GRT1-1670946819-1069287620) in one column and the body (GRT1CFV1x1143468254x199) in the second column.

while searching I came across "edeR" package in R, I tried using it, it gives me some error as 
`Error in .jcall("RJavaTools", "Ljava/lang/Object;", "invokeMethod", cl,  : 
  Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\Users\kishore\Documents\R\win-library\3.3\rJython\jython.jar\Lib\imaplib.py", line 501, in login
imaplib.error: [AUTHENTICATIONFAILED] Invalid credentials (Failure)`

I used `extractBetween(username="username",password="password",folder= "folder new",startDate="06-June-2017",endDate="06-July-2017", nmail=100)

The credentials are correct, there should be something else I'm not aware of. Anything would help here.

Comment: Sorry, but but what exactly is your single programming question here? You got a subject line and want a regex to extract a part from it? Or do you have an email string with headers, html parts, etc. and you want to extract the subject line from it? Or do you have an imap email account and you want to download a subset of emails or subject lines from it?

Comment: @lukeA I've an outlook account and want to download emails from a specific folder form a data table and then extract this `"FGD1-GRT1-1670946819-1069287620"` from subject line and "GRT1CFV1x1143468254x199" this from email body.

I'm currently able to get the emails from the outlook in ".csv" file and trying to extract subject and email body.

If there is anyother way which can directly pull the data from outlook and do the extraction then it would be magic for me.

Comment: Do you have I python installation besides R? In that case you can use the reticulate R package and pythons email and imaplib libraries. Downloading and/or parsing emails should be relatively easy with both. There are many examples on SO.

Comment: @lukeA, I don't have a litlle knowledge on python but yes I do have it.

Comment: @lukeA , can we not use any regex expression to extract the strings I need?

Comment: `library(stringr);txt  <- 'I want to extract "FGD1-GRT1-1670946819-1069287620" which is dynamic, from the subject line and in the body "GRT1CFV1x1143468254x199". The matter in subject has a common factor where it starts with the second part in the string in subject (GRT1).';str_extract_all(txt, "[[:alnum:]-]+[:digit:]+[:digit:]")
` matches both.

Comment: @lukeA, I just got some better output using `s <- "Thisispresent: FGD1-GRT1-1670946819-1069287620 ineverymail successfully"
> ss <- c(s,s,s)
> library(stringr)
> mat <- str_split_fixed(ss, "[_:-]", 11)[,-c(9, 10)]`

I'll try to merge the require string and get the output but still have to work on the body of the email.

Comment: @lukeA, bingo I got it luke thanks, I'm feeling a little stupid of myself.

Comment: can you please share a couple of links you were referring about python I would like to learn that please.

Comment: [Here](https://www.google.com/search?q=site:stackoverflow.com+python+imaplib+get+subject+line) is a starter. (I've little knowledge of python, too. However, using the many examples, it's not too difficult to put the things together.)

Comment: @lukeA, thank you appreciate it.